# For loop stopping before get to number needed

Tags: php, for-loop

My idea is to make tooltip for new users on website. They will go through the tooltips and each time they complete a tooltip it inserts into DB.

However i've got a button which is `skip all`. So my idea is to insert all the reminder tooltips which they've not completed into the DB with for loop.

So it works if there has been no tooltips clicked already. So the tooltip would be equal to `1` because coming through the `$data` is equal to `0`. However if the tooltip is equal to 1 when passed through `$data` it gets a `+1` and the `for loop` doesn't seem to post anything into `database`

```
$NumberOfTooltips = 2;
(int)$data->tooltipLastID = ((int)$data->tooltipLastID === 0) ? 1 : (int)$data->tooltipLastID + 1;     

for ($x = (int)$data->tooltipLastID; $x <= $NumberOfTooltips; $x++) {
   $query = "";
   $query = "INSERT INTO tooltips ";
   $query .= "(tooltip_id, inserted) VALUES ($x, NOW())";   
   database::query($query);
   $this->id = database::getInsertID();
}
```

On the broken loop the value of `(int)$data->tooltipLastID` is 2

Is it because the `(int)$data->tooltipLastID` is already equal to `$NumberOfTooltips`?

Comment: With a variable defined as `NumberOfTooltips = 2;` I'm surprised it even runs!

Comment: @Script47 sorry i missed the `$` off the variable

Comment: Should x++ be x--??? Or should >= be <=???

Comment: @Turtle Nope as that would make the `tooltipLastID = 0` basically when then `tooltipLastID` is equal to 1

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Write all tooltips to DB? A specific one? All up to one? All startig from one?

Comment: What is the type of `$data->tooltipLastID`? And plz use `var_dump((int)$data->tooltipLastID)` before the for loop to see what indeed x is.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Sorry i cannot follow you. for($x=1;$x>=2;$x++) seems not working

Comment: @Turtle also if you do `<=` it makes the loop never ending.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett No, the combination of `>=` and `++` makes it never ending.

Comment: @jeroen Yeah I finally find one guy who has the same idea with me :)

Comment: @Turtle I'm pretty sure we're not the only ones :-)

Comment: "for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement

The first expression (expr1) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.

In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. **If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues** and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends. " from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php - So, with your code, I'd expect it to _never_ execute the query.

Comment: @jeroen I've updated my question

Comment: @Martin Education

Comment: do you get an PHP errors?

Comment: @Martin No errors at all

Comment: @Turtle think you've got the right idea with the data type of `$data->tooltipLastID` because it's not the same as `NumberOfTooltips`

Comment: @ChrisBeckett OK. I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General improvements

> *These do not directly solve the question asked but they do give you a helping hand in clarifying your data and steaming out any secondary bugs and bloopers. Also pointing out some best (or at least, better) practise.*

- `$x` is a lazy and poorly defined counter. Prefer using descriptve veraibles such as `$tooltipCounter`
- `$data->tooltipLastID` should not *start* at 1; use the same syntax as every other integer number system in PHP/programming and start at zero. If you need a one then add `+1` only when it's needed (*`VALUES (".$x+1.")`*).
- `$NumberOfTooltips = 2;` The number 2 is probably not high enough for adequate testing.
- `var_dump($data->tooltipLastID)` and `var_dump($NumberOfTooltips)` to check both values are what you expect.
- Rewrite the test code to take the variables out of the code so that you can check your Database connction works correctly (such as if you're trying to insert into a string field-type by mistake)
- `$query = "";` is redundant.
- You should not need to type cast `(int)` your object variables (`$data->whatever`) all the time but type cast them when they're set.
- Also by adding `+1` to a variable PHP automatically recasts the variable as an `int` anyway.
- Check that your `$data->tooltipLastID` is publicly accessible/writable.
- You use `$this` ; so which class are you in? Are you self referencing the data class?
- A bank holiday is just one day.
- It is better the `inserted` Database column is set by the database automatically upon insert. You can use this SQL to alter your current table:

  ```
     ALTER TABLE <yourTable> MODIFY COLUMN inserted timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ```

Comment: I just re did everything and the problem was that the casting the data, it was because the types were not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Check the type of `$data->tooltipLastID`? And plz use `var_dump($data->tooltipLastID)` and `var_dump((int)$data->tooltipLastID)` before the for loop to see what indeed the original value and the $x is.

Strange type casts will result in strange bugs...

Comment: Surely the `var_dump` should not dump the cast but the original data?

Comment: @Martin Thanks. Edited.